# Move files listed in a text file while preserving/creating path

Tags: files, mv

I have a text file that has a list of files with full paths, with each line representing each file. For example, the first line from the file is:

```
/mnt/data/data4/1998/reports/First Quarter.docx
```

All the files share the same path up to the "data4" part (i.e. /mnt/data/data4). All I'm trying to do is to move each of these files to a different drive. So, for example, the above file would be moved to

```
/mnt/data/data11/1998/reports/First Quarter.docx
```

The "data11" part of the path would be constant and replace "data4" in the existing paths for all files. There are spaces in the text file and file names. In some cases, the part of the target path following /data11 will already exist, but in other cases it will not.

I imagine this can be done in a one liner using `sed`, `xargs`and `mv` but can't quite seem to figure it out. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are there any single quotes in the filenames?

Comment: Yes, quite a few.

Comment: You want those single quotes to be removed? You didn't mention this in the sample input file content

Comment: Sorry about that. No, I was hoping to preserve the filenames as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rsync`:

```
synclist=$(mktemp)
sed 's,^/mnt/data/data4/,,' filelist.txt > "$synclist"
rsync -avh --files-from="$synclist" --remove-source-files /mnt/data/data4/ /mnt/data/data11/
rm "$synclist"
```

1. Create a temporary file and assign it to variable `synclist`.
2. Remove prefix `/mnt/data/data4/` from all lines in `filelist.txt` and save the output in the temporary file.
3. Sync the files (which are now relative paths) in `$synclist` from `/mnt/data/data4/` to `/mnt/data/data11/`. Option `--remove-source-files` removes the source files after transfer (similar to `mv`).
4. Delete temporary file.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks again.